# SaveChanges - Creating new object in database (error)

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got an MVC4 project in Visual Studio 2013 which is currently a very basic website for a fictitious private flights company.

Here are my relevant files:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b744c44dc77084839e6d

I am trying to implement a form/ view for an admin to edit the existing user database. I've made the form successfully however I get an error when trying to save to the database.

EDIT: Database: http://gyazo.com/ff5d077b7f000ee78e372530b237696b

(Here's what the existing database looks like:
http://gyazo.com/a088c2cd75779b39bb343eca1aecb219

and this is what it looks like from the AdminIndex pov: http://gyazo.com/3a3533d07a96b4116554e0795df81a52)

In `MyTemplateController` (which is basically my HomeController) I have a section of code that is responsible for the creation of a new 'person' if you will.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SystemUser users)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //ss.StudentsTbls.AddObject(student); // Ignore this
            ss.SystemUsers.Add(users);
            ss.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AdminIndex");
        }

        return View(users);
    }
```

This is code is meant to save the information inserted by the user from `AdminIndex -> Create New` however, when I press create, I get the following error: http://gyazo.com/fe45ace191af8a6944f39217adb576a5

Would anyone be able to point out why this happens? Thanks.

EDIT: AdminIndex.cshtml and Create.cshtml https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fbd92ef0b1847efd2408

Comment: do you have primary key on your table?

Comment: @Pravat-MujahMaskey Yes sir: http://gyazo.com/ff5d077b7f000ee78e372530b237696b

Comment: I Had Same problem , I changed my primary key field into cascade mode . and i updated my enityframework

Comment: What does the 'EntityValidationErrors' property of your inner exception say?

Comment: @FredKleuver http://gyazo.com/76abec0464502ab0712cf1f62cf0721b

Comment: @salar Hi, thanks for the reply. How did you change this primary key into cascade mode/ updated entity framework?

Comment: @BorisSmith Hi. If you using sql server in table realations find Fk that you want and In botton of page change it into Cascade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityValidationErrors are tricky to work with if you're not aware of how this works internally.

The actual exception you'll want to catch is `DbEntityValidationException`.

This exception has a property `EntityValidationErrors`, which is an `IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult>`.

This `DbEntityValidationResult` then has a property `ValidationErrors`, which is an `IEnumerable<DbValidationError>`.

Finally, `DbValidationError` has a property `ErrorMessage`, which is where the actual meat is.

Wrapping your code in a try/catch block and getting these actual validation errors would look like this:

```
try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ss.SystemUsers.Add(users);
        ss.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("AdminIndex");
    }
    return View(users);

}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
            .SelectMany(e => e.ValidationErrors)
            .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
            .ToList();
    // Here you can see the actual validation errors when you're debugging
}
```

Of course, the fact that you get this exception in the first place means the validation rules on your controller do not match up with your database constraints.

This is a matter of personal preference, but I generally don't like to have my DAL catch validation errors. It should only be your last resort in case there are any bugs in the validation rules of your BLL. And you should treat them that way: make sure that next time these problems are caught in your Controllers (or Application / Business Layer) whenever you see them happen in your DAL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What should I be looking for in terms of finding the cause of the problem?

Comment: You should look at the errorMessages you get from catching the DbEntityValidationException. What do they say?

Comment: AH! Okay, I think I may have got the answer to this. At line `.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)` it mentions that I the passwordsalt is required. Password salt is also stored in the database and therefore I'm guessing it requires that too in the AdminIndex.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot with the error! Just to elaborate on my solution, I simply added the fields for the PasswordSalt in both the Create.cshtml and AdminIndex.cshtml. This was because of my original database where it had all fields that were required.

Comment: Makes sense, since your Password salt is marked with the `NOT NULL` attribute in your database. You might want to mark that field (and the other required ones) with the `[Required]` attribute in your MVC model so that your controller catches this error before your data layer does.

Comment: Have done so already if you check the original "Relevant Files" gist :) But yes, and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Write your code inside try catch block

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SystemUser users)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //ss.StudentsTbls.AddObject(student); // Ignore this
                ss.SystemUsers.Add(users);
                ss.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("AdminIndex");
            }        
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }

        return View(users);
    }
```

Now if you hover on exception or add it to the Watch and then navigate into the exception details  you will see which particular column(s) is/ are causing the error usually occurs when a table-constraint is voilated..

Comment: not inside bracket handle it through try catch block!!@BorisSmith